# Does MRPT_navigation work in HYDRO?

Tags: catkin-make, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to follow the steps described here: http://wiki.ros.org/mrpt_navigation/Tutorials/Installing but catkin_make gives me errors. My steps are:
1)sudo apt-get install libmrpt-dev
2)cd <your_catkin_ws>/src
3)git clone https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg/mrpt_navigation.git
4)cd ..
5)catkin_make

After that, when building mrpt_navigation it gives me this:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/CMakeFiles/mrpt_bridge.dir/src/point_cloud2.cpp.o
Building CXX object mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/CMakeFiles/mrpt_bridge.dir/src/point_cloud.cpp.o
/home/arms/catkin_ws/src/mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/src/pose.cpp: In function ‘mrpt::poses::CPose3D& mrpt_bridge::convert(const tf::Transform&, mrpt::poses::CPose3D&)’:
/home/arms/catkin_ws/src/mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/src/pose.cpp:87:10: error: ‘class mrpt::poses::CPose3D’ has no member named ‘setRotationMatrix’
/home/arms/catkin_ws/src/mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/src/point_cloud2.cpp: In function ‘bool mrpt_bridge::copy(const mrpt::slam::CSimplePointsMap&, const Header&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&)’:
/home/arms/catkin_ws/src/mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/src/point_cloud2.cpp:108:55: note: #pragma message: TODO: "Implement pointcloud2 mrpt2ros"

[ 52%] Building CXX object mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/CMakeFiles/mrpt_bridge.dir/src/laser_scan.cpp.o

[ 55%] Building CXX object mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/CMakeFiles/mrpt_bridge.dir/src/map.cpp.o

make[2]: *** [mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/CMakeFiles/mrpt_bridge.dir/src/pose.cpp.o] Error 1

make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Linking CXX shared library /home/arms/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmrpt_localization_core.so
[ 55%] Built target mrpt_localization_core
Scanning dependencies of target mrpt_localization

[ 61%] [ 61%] Building CXX object mrpt_navigation/mrpt_localization/CMakeFiles/mrpt_localization.dir/src/mrpt_localization/mrpt_localization_parameters.cpp.o
Building CXX object mrpt_navigation/mrpt_localization/CMakeFiles/mrpt_localization.dir/src/mrpt_localization/mrpt_localization.cpp.o
make[1]: *** [mrpt_navigation/mrpt_bridge/CMakeFiles/mrpt_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX shared library /home/arms/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmrpt_localization.so

[ 61%] Built target mrpt_localization

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make" failed
```

In my src/mrpt_navigation there are multiple mrpt folders and when I run roslaunch mrpt_localization demo.launch
it gives me: Error: cannot launch node of type [mrpt_localization/mrpt_localization_node]: cant locate node in package
Could anyone please help?

I am using ROS Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04

[edit] added full error message

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202874/does-mrpt_navigation-work-in-hydro?/) by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-11**:
Please edit your question to include the full error that you get when running catkin_make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best solution is to remove the system version of mrpt, which is quite old in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get remove libmrpt-dev mrpt-apps
```

then installing a **more recent version**. You have 2 options:

1. Build from sources, either [cloning master from GitHub](https://github.com/jlblancoc/mrpt) or [downloading](http://www.mrpt.org/download-mrpt/) the last stable version. Building instructions can be found [here](http://www.mrpt.org/Building_and_Installing_Instructions).
2. Installing with `apt-get` via the [PPA repository](http://www.mrpt.org/MRPT_in_GNU/Linux_repositories).

Cheers,
JL

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) with karma: 288 on 2015-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2015-03-11**:
Thank you Very much, Jose! that helped.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-03-13**:
I installed the more recent version from the PPA repository.
Then, `export MRPT_DIR=YOUR_MRPT_BUILD_DIR`

But when I went to the [MRPT Git Repository](https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg/mrpt_navigation), there was only the ROS Indigo distribution.
I'm working with Hydro, where can I find it?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) on 2015-03-14**:
@kost9: Great!

@sealguy77: Just clone the branch named "indigo", it should work on hydro too. In the future we'll probably rename the branch to "master" or alike to avoid confusion.

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2015-03-14**:
Hi Jose!
thanks for your help again!

Another question: **Does mrpt_localization package rely on odometry messages from robot?**
I used a slam method to generate a map that doesnt need odometry, since my robot doesnt provide odometry data.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) on 2015-03-15**:
Yes, `mrpt_localization` relies on odometry, but if it is not present it should still be able to track the robot just from laser scans (increase the "uncertainty parameters" a bit to make the particles spread more than usual). If it doesn't work open an issue on GitHub or try to fix and pull-request

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2015-03-17**:
A) Thanks for help, Jose!
I tried following but had no luck.
So far I used your demo.launch file as a template:

1. I tried feeding my own map (.pgm, .tiff formats) but those didnt load.
2. changed r1/front_laser/scan to just /scan (I provide scan topic)
3. not sure how to set up tf transform

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2015-03-17**:
B) generally I dont know how to set this launch file up.

in terminal I get this error :
Failed to subtract global_frame (map) from odom_frame (r1/odom)

I am only providing /scan topic and I have a ready map (previously generated in rviz by hector_slam)

I would very much appreciate your help!